# Running a function when a widget window is brought to the front?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm building a gui front-end for a project I've been working on, and I'm having trouble figuring out this specific aspect of PyQT. Long ago there was a post that I had that I think would've solved the problem but I can't quite find it.

Regardless, I have the following files, main.py and playlistcreator.py respectively:

(main.py)

```
import getpass
import playlistcreator
import os
import sys
import sip

sip.setapi('QString', 2)
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


# Window class
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):  # constructor for Window (passes "self" -aka Window- to __init__ to initialize it)
        super(Window, self).__init__()  # inherits from QMainWindow
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 150)  # Set window dimensions
        self.setWindowTitle("Google Music Playlist Transfer")  # Set window title
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gmusic.png'))  # Set window icon

        self.login = QWidget()  # login widget ("front page")
        self.processing = QWidget()  # on successful login - being processing data
        self.file_inputs = QWidget()  # after processing, ask user where they would like to store data

        # call functions
        self.loginUI()
        self.processingUI()
        self.file_inputsUI()

        # create stacked widget and add layouts to stack
        self.Stack = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.Stack.addWidget(self.login)
        self.Stack.addWidget(self.processing)
        self.Stack.addWidget(self.file_inputs)

        main_box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_box.addWidget(self.Stack)

        self.setLayout(main_box)
        self.show()

    def loginUI(self):
        # Set email field
        self.email = QLineEdit()
        self.email.setMaxLength(110)
        self.email.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        # Set password field
        self.pwd = QLineEdit()
        self.pwd.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.pwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        # Form layout
        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow("Email: ", self.email)
        form_layout.addRow("Password: ", self.pwd)

        # Login button
        self.login_btn = QPushButton("Login", self)  # login button
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.process_login)  # tell button what to do
        self.login_btn.resize(self.login_btn.sizeHint())

        # Quit button
        self.quit_btn = QPushButton("Exit", self)  # exit button
        self.quit_btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)  # tell button what to do

        # Error label layout
        self.error_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Button box layout
        button_box = QHBoxLayout()
        button_box.addStretch(1)
        button_box.addWidget(self.login_btn)
        button_box.addWidget(self.quit_btn)

        # input layout (main layout for "home")
        input_box = QVBoxLayout()
        input_box.addLayout(self.error_layout)
        input_box.addLayout(form_layout)
        input_box.addLayout(button_box)
        self.login.setLayout(input_box)

    def processingUI(self):
        # setup layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        # alert user that we're grabbing track data
        self.progress_label = QLabel("Grabbing tracks from Google Music. . .")
        self.progress_label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 100, 0);")
        layout.addWidget(self.progress_label)

        # Get users list of "thumbs up" tracks from Google Music

        # set layout
        favorite_tracks = self.get_tracks
        self.processing.setLayout(layout)

    def file_inputsUI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        # Set text field for directory
        self.dir_textbox = QTextEdit(self)
        # Add textbox to layout
        layout.addRow("Music Directory: ", self.dir_textbox)
        self.file_inputs.setLayout(layout)

    def close_application(self):
        confirm = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit Confirmation',
                                       "Are you sure you want to exit?",
                                       QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if confirm == QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

    def process_login(self):
        email_input = str(self.email.text())
        pwd_input = str(self.pwd.text())
        login_successful = playlistcreator.login(email_input, pwd_input)
        if login_successful:
            self.Stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        else:
            self.error_label = QLabel("Please check your email/password!")
            self.error_label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
            self.error_layout.addWidget(self.error_label)

    def get_tracks(self):
        tracks = playlistcreator.get_favorite_tracks()
        print("You have ", len(tracks), " favorite tracks!")
        return tracks

    # def open_dir_dialog(self):
    #     directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select USB Drive Location')
    #     self.myTextBox.setText(fileName)


def main():
    # Create an PyQT5 application object.
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    # # Input Music Directory
    # music_dir = input("Please put the path to your music folder: ")
    # list_of_paths = playlistcreator.findmp3(music_dir, favorite_tracks)
    # # Input playlist file save location
    # playlist_path = input("Where would you like to save the playlist?: ")
    # playlist_name = input("What would you like to name the playlist? ")
    # playlist_name += ".m3u8"
    # # Testing appending file extension to string
    # playlistcreator.addtoplaylist(list_of_paths, playlist_path, playlist_name)
    # playlistcreator.logout()


main()
```

(playlistcreator.py)

```
import os
from gmusicapi import Mobileclient
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

api = Mobileclient()
songCount = 0
favorite_files_path = []
logged_in = False


def login(email, password):
    library = []
    if "@" not in email:
        email += "@gmail.com"
    logged_in = api.login(email, password, Mobileclient.FROM_MAC_ADDRESS)
    return logged_in


def get_favorite_tracks():
    print("Getting songs from Google Music. . .")
    library = api.get_all_songs()
    print("There are", len(library), "items in your music library")
    good_songs = [song for song in library if song['rating'] == '5']
    print("You have", len(good_songs), "favorite tracks!")
    return good_songs


def logout():
    api.logout()


def findmp3(rootFolder, favoriteTracks):
    print("Searching for favorite tracks. . .")
    for directory, subdirectory, files in os.walk(rootFolder, topdown=False):  # for all files in directory
        global songCount
        global favorite_files_path
        for mp3 in files:  # for files in 
            if mp3.endswith(".mp3"):  # if file ends with .mp3
                file_path = os.path.join(directory, mp3)  # concatenate to create full path
                try:
                    file_tags = EasyID3(file_path)  # grab file tags from mp3 file
                except:
                    file_tags = EasyID3()  # create tags if none are found
                    file_tags.save(file_path)  # save file to have new tags
                if "title" in file_tags:
                    fileTitle = file_tags["title"][0]  # TIT2 = corresponding tag in mutagen for song title
                else:
                    fileTitle = "None"
                if "artist" in file_tags:
                    fileArtist = file_tags["artist"][0]  # TPE = corresponding tag in mutagen for artist
                else:
                    fileArtist = "None"
                if "album" in file_tags:
                    fileAlbum = file_tags["album"][0]  # TALB = corresponding tag in mutagen for album
                else:
                    fileAlbum = "None"
                for track in favoriteTracks:
                    gMusicTitle = track["title"]
                    gMusicArtist = track["artist"]
                    gMusicAlbum = track["album"]
                    if fileTitle in gMusicTitle and fileArtist in gMusicArtist and fileAlbum in gMusicAlbum:  # if file tags (artist, album, title) match gMusic tags
                        songCount += 1
                        if songCount == 1:
                            print("Found 1 song")
                        else:
                            print("Found", songCount, "songs")  # print updated count of found tracks
                        favorite_files_path.append(file_path)  # add all found files to a list (via their paths)
                        break  # break out of "for track in favorite tracks"
    return favorite_files_path


def addtoplaylist(paths, playlist_path, playlist_name):
    # Open file (or create if it does not exist)
    # change to given directory
    try:
        os.chdir(playlist_path)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    # open file - if it does not exist, create it
    with open(playlist_name, 'a+', encoding="UTF-8") as playlistFile:
        print("Adding tracks...", end="")
        for track in paths:
            print(".", end="")
            playlistFile.write(track + '\n')
    playlistFile.close()
```

The problem I've been running into is when the user logs in they hit the processingUI window (which states that the program is grabbing all their tracks from Google) but it doesn't actually seem to be running the get_tracks() method (which is what actually gets the user's tracks from Google), as the program hangs there and doesn't do anything.

I've tested the program without a GUI using straight command line, and it works flawlessly, but I'm not sure what the issue is with the GUI - do I need to thread the execution to start when the proper "window" is brought to the front?

Comment: You need to run the code that hits the Google API in a separate QThread. When the results are returned, you need to transfer them to the UI controls, but this needs to be done on the original thread that created the controls. The Qt signals/slots are often used to make this easier.

Comment: I thought I commented on this but I guess I dreamt it - thanks a bunch @DavidChing I'm gonna read up on that.